# Update connectionString value is not working

Tags: c#, runtime, connection-string

I'm trying to update some config files on runtime.  One file is being updated but connectionString values are not being changed.

Here is my code

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
config.AppSettings.Settings["ServerDSN"].Value=newValue;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder builder = null;

foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connString in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    if (connString.Name == "myConnectionString")
    {
        Configuration config2 = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
        //Configuration config2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connString.ToString());
        builder.ProviderConnectionString = string.Format(";database Name={0};host=localhost;", db);
        config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }
}
```

THANKS

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Modifications to the web.config will restart the app pool.

Comment: If you really want to build connection string dynamically (though that's weird) then what's the point in setting it in `web.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
config.AppSettings.Settings["ServerDSN"].Value=newValue;
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString = string.Format(";database Name={0};host=localhost;", db);
config.Save();
```